# constructing object from temporary

Tags: c++, constructor, temporary-objects, object-construction

I'm using a third-party class with (only) constructor as follows

```
class foo  // cannot be altered
{
  public:
    explicit foo(std::istream&);
  ...
};
```

and the documentation of which suggests the following approach

```
std::ifstream from("file.txt");
foo obj(from);
from.close();
```

I cannot alter `foo` and want to use as member of another class

```
class bar
{
     foo obj;                           // must not be altered
   public:
     explicit
     bar(std::string const&filename)    // must not be altered
       : obj(std::ifstream(filename))   // error: no matching constructor
   {}
   ...
};
```

except that this does not work, since the temporary `std::ifstream` created from the `filename` is not guaranteed to live long enough to construct the `foo obj` and hence cannot be converted to a `std::istream&` (the situation would be different, if `foo::foo()` accepted a `const std::istream&`).

So my question: can I make the constructor of `bar` to work without changing the design of `bar` (for example, `bar::bar()` to take a `std::istream&`, or bar to hold a `std::unique_ptr<foo>` instead of a `foo` or by adding data members to `bar`)?

Comment: Have `bar` take a `std::istream&` and pass that to `obj`?

Comment: @NathanOliver that would alter the design of `bar` in an unwanted way

Comment: If `foo::foo` accepted a `const istream&`, you would have undefined behaviour instead. Not an improvement, in my opinion.

Comment: @molbdnilo Can you elaborate on that? I thought that this is well defined behaviour: a temporary will live as long as const refs to it, no?

Comment: "... without changing the design of `bar`" do you mean " ... without changing the design of `foo`" ?

Comment: apparently not, then I dont understand the question :/

Comment: @idclev463035818 I meant what I said: no change to `foo` at all, no change to the basic design of `bar`: same constructor interface, same members.

Comment: If you don't want `bar` to hold onto the ifstream object, there you have to take it in in the constructor.  `foo` requires an lvalue and the only way to create one on the fly is to use `new` but if you don't hold onto the pointer then you have a memory leak.

Comment: does wrapping `bar` in a `moo` count as "changing the design" ?

Comment: @Walter They ;ive as long as the first binding, which is the constructor parameter. If `foo` doesn't store the stream, but only uses it for construction, it would be fine - *if* you could read from a const stream, but you can't.

Comment: @NathanOliver What if I have an object that keeps a `mutable std::ifstream` and allows `const` type conversion to an `std::ifstream&` -- would that be okay?

Comment: @Walter Where are you going to keep that?  At that point you should just have a `ifstream` member in `bar`.

Comment: @NathanOliver keep it nowhere, but use a temporary of that object type and pass it to the constructor of `foo` -- at least the clang compiler gives no errors anymore.

Comment: @Walter That doesn't work.  Temporary lifetime extension only works with function local references.  Passing a temporary to a constructor where the object holds onto a reference to it does not extend the lifetime and will leave you with a dangling reference.

Answer (score 2):

Your design constraints are impossible to satisfy. The safest one to relax is to hold onto a `std::ifstream` in `bar`.

```
class bar
{
     std::ifstream objs_stream;         // must be declared before obj
     foo obj;                           // must not be altered
   public:
     explicit
     bar(std::string const&filename)    // must not be altered
       : objs_stream(filename), obj(objs_stream)
   {}
   ...
};
```

Another option would be to submit a patch to the third party class:

```
class foo
{
  public:
    explicit foo(std::istream&);
    explicit foo(std::istream&& is) : foo(is) {}
  ...
};
```

If `foo` has a copy or move constructor, you could

```
foo make_foo(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream is(filename);
    return foo(is);
}

class bar
{
     foo obj;                           // must not be altered
   public:
     explicit
     bar(std::string const&filename)    // must not be altered
       : obj(make_foo(filename))
   {}
   ...
};
```

Comment: Sorry, but that was explicitly excluded as solution.

Comment: Yep.  Design can't be done, so this is a valid work around.

Comment: @Walter no other part of `bar` need interact with `objs_stream`

Comment: @NathanOliver pls look at my alternative answer. According to your comment, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following possibility (which compiles w/o errors).

```
class bar
{
    foo obj;                           // must not be altered
    struct tmp {
       mutable std::ifstream s;
       tmp(std::string const&f) : s(f) {}
       operator std::istream&() const { return s; }
    };
  public:
    explicit
    bar(std::string const&filename)    // must not be altered
      : obj(tmp(filename))
  {}
  ...
};
```

Is this okay? I.e. will `tmp::s` live until the construction of `obj` returns (which according to the documentation of `foo`, see edited question, is sufficient)?

Comment: This will leave you with a dangling reference and `foo`'s use of the stream will have undefined behavior.  The compiler is not required to diagnose this.

Comment: @NathanOliver can you elaborate on this? Note that `obj` does not hold onto the reference/pointer to its constructor's argument (see edited question).

Comment: As soon as `obj(tmp(filename))` finishes, `s` from `tmp` is destroyed which means that the stream reference `obj` has is referring to an object that no longer exists.  If `obj` needs to use the stream after it's constructed, then that uses will use a dangling reference which is UB.  If `obj` only use the stream in the constructor then you're safe, but that requires everyone working on this to know that, so it imposes documentation requirements.

Comment: @NathanOliver *If obj needs to use the stream after it's constructed* it doesn't. I had hoped that was made clear in the question. I know that the design of `foo` is poor, but I cannot do anything about that.